# Reference for a property of convex function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis

Let $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function.

It is known that if $F$ has a strict local maximum, then it is not a convex function.

I just would like to ask you for a proper classic reference for that, I mean, a book where I can find that statement proved (or something similar).

ADDITION: I am just asking for a book where all those basic concepts involving convexity are dealt, no matter whether this very specific statement is proved or not.

EDITED: I replaced *an absolute maximum* with *strict local maximum*.

Comment: I expect you will find many books proving that the graph of a convex function lies above any of its tangent planes; this result is a trivial consequence of that. And so I very much doubt that you will find a reference writing up this special case as a separate theorem – it is just too easy.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen, that is why I have edited my question to deal with *strict local maximum*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $F$ has a strict local maximum at $x^*\in\mathbb R$. Then, there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(x^*)>f(x)$ for all $x\in U$, where $U\equiv(x^*-\varepsilon,x^*+\varepsilon)\setminus\{x^*\}$.

To obtain a contradiction, suppose that $F$ is convex. Let $x_1\equiv x^*-\varepsilon/2$ and $x_2\equiv x^*+\varepsilon/2$. Clearly, $x_1,x_2\in U$ and $(x_1+x_2)/2=x^*$. By convexity and strict maximality of $x^*$, $$f(x^*)=f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)\leq\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}\underbrace{<}_{!!!}\frac{f(x^*)+f(x^*)}{2}=f(x^*),$$
which is a contradiction.

I don't know of any standalone references for this; I just made up the proof myself, using the definitions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is not exactly what I was asking for, but it actually *helps*.

Comment: @Vicent Are you trying to locate a particular textbook you remember seeing this result in but can't remember the title of?

Comment: No, just asking for a *good* book that deals with this topic.

Comment: by the way, out of curiosity, is that $\underbrace{\;}_{!!!}$ a kind of standard notation?

Comment: Haha, no, it's not, I just inserted it to emphasize the strictness of the inequality, ultimately leading to the contradiction. As for your question, am I right in conjecturing that what you really are looking for is a solid and comprehensive calculus/real analysis textbook? If so, two very popular and great references are [Tao and Rudin](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373401/self-study-real-analysis-tao-or-rudin), but there are many, [many others](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298289/which-mathematical-analysis-i-book-or-textbook-is-the-best).

Comment: Thank you! I am going to mark your answer as *accepted answer*, as you gave the proof and also a reference book in the comments.

Comment: @Vicent Thank you, I hope it helped.